# How to call parent UserControl method from a child UserControl in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have to use the result of a parent usercontrol method in child usercontrol.How to find the method in child control?

Comment: you can use the parent property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.parent.aspx

Comment: Why do you need to access your "parent", that hardwires it with a parent which makes it less reusable. Instead a child communicates via [`events`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) with his parent. So the parent **can** handle the UC-child's event (but it doesn't necessarily need to).

Comment: check the edit ofr the answer might work for you

Answer (score 11):

User controls exists to make our code more reusable, user controls can be placed in any page, some page could have these two user controls, some pages not, so you can't ensure that the page will have the two user controls.
In my opinion, the best way to do it is using events. The idea is the following: the child usercontrol raises one event, the page where this user control is placed handles this event and calls the event of the parent user control, in this way, your code is still reusable.

So, the code of child control would be the following

```
public partial class Child : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // here, we declare the event
    public event EventHandler OnChildEventOccurs;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // some code ...
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        results.Add("Item1");
        results.Add("Item2");

        // this code says: when some one is listening this event, raises this and send one List of string as parameters
        if (OnChildEventOccurs != null)
            OnChildEventOccurs(results, null);
    }
}
```

And the page needs to handle the occurrence of this event, like this

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // the page will listen for when the event occurs in the child
        Child1.OnChildEventOccurs += new EventHandler(Child1_OnChildEventOccurs);
    }

    void Child1_OnChildEventOccurs(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you will be notified when the method occurs in your child control.
        // once you know that the method occurs you can call the method of the parent and pass the parameters received
        Parent1.DoSomethingWhenChildRaisesYourEvent((List<string>)sender);
    }
}
```

And finally the method that does something in the parent control.

```
 public void DoSomethingWhenChildRaisesYourEvent(List<string> lstParam)
    {
        foreach (string  item in lstParam)
        {
            // Just show the strings on the screen
            lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text + " " + item;
        }
    }
```

This way, your page acts as an orchestrator of events.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

you can create method like this to get parentcontrol in child control

```
public ofparentcontroltype GetParentControl(Control ctrl)
{
   if(ctrl.Parent is ofparentcontroltype)
    {
     return ((ofparentcontroltype)this.Parent);
    }
  else if  (ctrl.Parent==null)
     return null;

     GetParentControl(ctrl.Parent);
}
```

call to method is like following

```
ofparentcontroltype parent = GetParentControl(this);
if(parent!=null)
 var data = ((ofparentcontroltype)this.Parent).methodtocall();
```

---

Do something like this in codebehind of the usercontrol

```
if(this.Parent is ofparentcontroltype)
{
 var data = ((ofparentcontroltype)this.Parent).methodtocall();
}
```

Check the Example here : 
[**Access Parent Control's Method from a Child Control**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27626/Access-Parent-Control-s-Method-from-a-Child-Contro)

Comment: I have tried this but following error is shown, Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'TowerClearance.UserControls.ucPagedClearanceRequestList'.

Comment: @aamirghafoor - is your usercontrol is in div like control which having runat="server" than this should be case, in that case check "this.Parent.Parent" ..or need to write while loop till you find the parent control of your type